# Button in TableViewCell to go open Maps app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableViewCell, which has the following code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var tr: newTracks!
    if inSearchMode {
        tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        tr = items[indexPath.row]
    }
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tr.lat,tr.lon)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
    mapItem.name = tr.name
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey :MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
    }
```

the tr variable links to a struct I have that collects various data about a site, including latitude and longitude.  This works great, when i select a row from my Tableview it opens apple maps and plots a route from current location to the row location.

What I want to do is implement a button on the tableviewcell called locate that only when you press the button does it open apple maps and plot the route as above.

Could somebody help me understand how to implement the button and where my code needs to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you can use closure. Here's the sample code.

1. In CustomTableViewCell, we added completion and target for button. When button pushed, completion will be called.

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

var completion: ((Void) -> Void?)?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTappedButton), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func didTappedButton() {
    if let completion = completion {
        completion()
    }
}
```

}

2. In your UITableView `cellForRow` make sure you cast to CustomTableView and assign the completion property. Inside the `cell.completion` closure you can call any action that you want.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
       cell.completion = {
           print("Button tapped")
       }
       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: This doesnt work for me.  When I add my own code into cell.complettion {} I get an error "Missing return in a closure expected to return Void"  

The code I am entering is the 4 lines startting with "let coordinate" in my original post

Comment: sorted it, needed to add return() to the end of my code

Answer (score 0):

1) **Create a custom class-:**

```
class FruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var buttonClick: UIButton!
}
```

2) **Use cellForRowAt indexPath method-:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell


cell.buttonClick.tag = 1; 
cell.buttonClick.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

3) **Implement your target method with required code**-:

```
 func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

 if (sender.tag == 1) 
     {
         var tr: newTracks!
        if inSearchMode {
            tr = filteredTrack[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            tr = items[indexPath.row]
        }
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tr.lat,tr.lon)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
        mapItem.name = tr.name
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey :MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
     }

    }
```

Comment: What's this `if (sender.tag == 0)` for?

Comment: @nayem just a reference to your button.

Comment: Good that you've updated your answer. Else I was wondering how you would compare `if (sender.tag == 0)` when you set `cell.buttonClick.tag = indexPath.row;`?

Comment: sorry to sound so dumb,  I already have a custom class, Does all 3 blocks of code you provided go inside the custom class?  I have cellForRowAt method in ViewController already?  just a bit confused as to where to put the code.

Comment: @Jade Reynolds just my first step goes in custom class.All rest in view controller .

Comment: ok great, on this line

"buttonClick.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)"

I get use of unresolved identifier 'buttonClick'

Comment: @Jade Reynolds use cell.buttonClick.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)"

Comment: ok this now compiles, but when i click the button i get Fatal error found nil